# Submit GET request to two servers

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a production environment with two servers. I have a page where users submit data, and click save, and the database is updated with the information that was submitted. After this happens, I need to send a GET request to the two servers. These requests basically run methods to get the data that was updated, and save it into memory. I have been using jQuery to call the URLs like this:

```
$.ajax({<br />
    type : "GET",<br />
    url : 'http://IP_ADDRESS1/contextRoot1/servlet1?param=value&param2=value2'<br />
});

$.ajax({<br />
    type : "GET",<br />
    url : 'http://IP_ADDRESS1/contextRoot2/servlet1?param=value&param2=value2'<br />
});

$.ajax({<br />
    type : "GET",<br />
    url : 'http://IP_ADDRESS1/contextRoot3/servlet1?param=value&param2=value2'<br />
});

$.ajax({<br />
    type : "GET",<br />
    url : 'http://IP_ADDRESS2/contextRoot1/servlet1?param=value&param2=value2'<br />
});

$.ajax({<br />
    type : "GET",<br />
    url : 'http://IP_ADDRESS2/contextRoot2/servlet1?param=value&param2=value2'<br />
});

$.ajax({<br />
    type : "GET",<br />
    url : 'http://IP_ADDRESS2/contextRoot3/servlet1?param=value&param2=value2'<br />
});
```

I need to use the IP addresses of the machine because I have a load balancer, that forwards to requests to which ever machine is being least used when he gets a request to the domain. I am also pretty sure jQuery won't do 6 ajax requests. I am also having trouble with jQuery and the cross domain constraint. I tried using jQuery-xdomain-ajax.js, but it's a piece of junk (it didn't work for me). I kind of have a solution, but I am just wondering if there is a better one. My solution now is to have a popup open, and submit the other three ajax requests to the other server. I can't have an external process calling the request every so often.

Two app servers are JBoss with web servers that are Apache
One database server is MySQL
OS is linux on app servers and database server

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you storing this "in-memory" data in memcached or similar?

Comment: But **why** is this being done via the client? This can all be moved server-server if you ask me.

Comment: Define the in memory location.  Is it the session?  Are you trying to synchronize between two MySQL instances?  It might be easier to setup a shared session store between the two JBoss servers, replication in MySQL with one master and another could be promoted, etc.  I think you might be trying to synchronize everything in the wrong place.  Too much can go wrong.  One Ajax call works and the other fails, etc.

Comment: agree with Robin Maben, cross domain request in ajax can be simulated using server side where you make single ajax post to local path and your server code can forward it anywhere or split into multiple requests to different ips then send back response to your ajax.

Comment: The memory location is a Singleton object in the app. I am curious now, how can server side code post a request to another server? Any examples or links. Lucas, any links or info on the shared session store.

Comment: To be clearer, I updated the server info, and I need to synchronize the two jboss servers, and each of its apps with the database.

Comment: So I got this to work with 6 pop ups all doing a regular form submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put some data in a in memory store, you should use Infinispan the distributed cached bundle with JBoss as 7.

In this document you can find how to create a container and how to access the Inifinspan cache via injection.

With the use of Inifinspan each JBoss node will have access to the same shared cache and you will get scalable and highly available solution.